# skydrive and mvvm on wp8

Tags: c#, mvvm, onedrive, windows-phone-8

I’ve got a few questions which i hope you can help me with in regards to using SkyDrive with a wp8 app.

1. Does the live sdk support mvvm pattern? I’ve tried implementing standard code to login in my viewmodel, but it keeps throwing me a strange error i.e. Filenotfound for presentation library. When i implemented on a view it works. Any idea?
2. I know my internet speed is slow (poor connection from where i am on holidays!!), but should i really display a progress bar of some sort?
3. My sign in button is in my settings page but I’m not sure where should i auto-login from as I’ve got a splash screen page that loads up first but based on options selected in my settings, the next page loading could be any of the 3 available and I’m not sure where i should implement this if it doesn’t support mvvm. Should i duplicate the code in all 3 pages? Then what, assuming i do and i auto-login to my skydrive, the data i want to upload is done from another page, what do i do for that? The idea is that i want login so i don’t have to do it when it’s time to upload the data.

Any help clarifying these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

T